# Configure ODBC Azure linked service in Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-synapse

Where I can find the connection string in the Azure linked service for odbc as attached in screenshot. [Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcLnw.png)

Comment: You need to specify the driver, server and database details in the connection string or specify system DSN you set up Integration Runtime. Refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties).

Comment: Hi Aswin, thank you.    Name of the DSN is enough or should I need to add something else with it?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to specify DSN in connection string

Answer (score 0):

- Enter the connection String details with below format.
  `Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server.database.windows.net; Database=TestDatabase;`
  or
  `DSN=<name of the DSN on IR machine>;`

> The connection string excluding the credential portion. You can specify the connection string with pattern like  `Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server.database.windows.net; Database=TestDatabase;`, or use the system DSN (Data Source Name) you set up on the Integration Runtime machine with  `DSN=<name of the DSN on IR machine>;`  (you need still specify the credential portion in linked service accordingly).   You can also put a password in Azure Key Vault and pull the `password` configuration out of the connection string.

- Connect via **Self hosted integrated Runtime **
- Give the authentication type.
- Enter username, password if authentication type is basic.
- Enter the credential.

> The access credential portion of the connection string specified in
> driver-specific property-value format. Example: `"RefreshToken=<secret refresh token>;"`. Mark this field as a SecureString.

**Reference:** **MS doc** on [ODBC Linked Service Properties in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties)